# Is there a deprecated flag in clearcase?

Tags: version-control, visibility, clearcase, deprecated, cleartool

**Is there any way in Clearcase to set a file as deprecated?**

**My(Use)-case:**

I have a project (a simulation environment) which has some (old) version. I realized that my directory structure is bad during the developing. I want to put some files to another directory. I can do it, but in this case some files are seems as duplicated. If I delete the old file the old versions of the environment won't run. (And some cases I have to run the old versions of the simulation environment.)

**Problem: Obsolete files can be confusing.**

**What I expect:**

A deprecated flag would be nice. If it is set the file is not visible with `element * /main/LATEST` configspec sentence. But if I set `element * LABEL_TO_VERSION_1` I will be able to see the deprecated file. Is there anything something like this?

I don't want to see the file vith `element * /main/LATEST`

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want to see the file vith element * /main/LATEST

First, put a label ([`cleartool mklabel`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-41)) on the current old version.

Then use [cleartool mv](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mv.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.1%2F4-0-0-0-1-46) to move/rename elements, or delete some extra files you don't want.

`element * /main/LATEST` will show you the newest organization, but you can create another view with the config spec:

```
element * LABEL_TO_VERSION_1
element * /main/LATEST
```

That second view will show you the older organization.